# how to extract the numbers above and below the diagonal of a matrix into two separate vectors in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am new to matlab. I have large N X N matrix and i need to extract the numbers above the diagonal in a vector and the same with the numbers below the diagonal, but into a separate vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`diag`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diag.html) which extracts numbers in a matrix along a diagonal.  The default behaviour is to extract the values over the main diagonal of a matrix (i.e. the row and column numbers are the same), but you can specify an additional parameter that specifies an offset of whether you want to sample above or below the main diagonal.

As such, if you want to go one above the diagonal, you'd specify the second parameter as `1`.  To go below, you'd specify the second parameter as `-1`.

Let's show an example with a 5 x 5 matrix `A`, like so:

```
A = reshape(1:25, 5, 5)

A = 

 1     6    11    16    21
 2     7    12    17    22
 3     8    13    18    23
 4     9    14    19    24
 5    10    15    20    25
```

To get the diagonal right above the main diagonal, you would do:

```
vec1 = diag(A,1)
```

Our output is:

```
vec1 =

 6
12
18
24
```

Similarly, to get the diagonal right below the main diagonal, you would do:

```
vec2 = diag(A,-1)
```

Our output is:

```
vec2 =

 2
 8
14
20
```

Comment: I have done that. What I am trying to get is one vector with the diagonal entries and anther with all the entries that are not the diagonal.

Comment: @pj45 That's not what your question is asking.  You said you wanted diagonal entries either above or below the main diagonal.  You **did not** specify you wanted entries not on the diagonal.  You should change your question description, or create another question all together.